# Build events in Visual Studio API and post-build step execution order

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, post-build-event

in my project I have defined a post-build step, where the linked executable is moved to another directory. Now I wrote an addin for the Visual Studio, which handles the build events and do some actions on the linked executable after the build. My problem is, the post-build step of the Visual Studio is executed before the post-build event (OnBuildDone) is raised, so the executable is already moved from the build directory. How can I ensure, that my addin is executed before the post-build step of the VS?

Comment: Never heard of "PostBuildEvents", only BuildDone.  What are you using?

Comment: I mean the BuildEvents (e.g. OnBuildDone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answer here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/58d8c785-e0c1-42e9-8092-726964f12044/

The short version:
"The Post Build event is actually a part of MsBuild. That’s why the OnBuildDone is fired after the PostBuildEvent."